# Javascript tabifier not working in Chrome, but works fine on Firefox

Tags: javascript

I have little knowledge of javascript so I hope someone here could help me. The problem occurs on http://www.bestfreeandroidapps.com/ if you look on the right side there are 3 tabs with Categories, Comments and Recent Posts. When you click on them from Chrome, nothing happens (no errors in the console, just nothing), however it works fine in Firefox.

This theme uses a script calle Javascript tabifier from http://www.barelyfitz.com/projects/tabber/, however I even replaced the script on the theme with what was included in the original project and still doesn't work on Chrome. Does anyone have an idea of what might be wrong and why is this happening?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Make a reproducible example and post the code.  Otherwise, your question is of no use to others that look for an answer in the future.

Comment: It's working fine for me in Chrome 25 on OSX

Comment: Also, marking questions as "Answerd gives you higher rating.

Answer (score 0):

It works. I think its being cached by the browser, I've had similar problems lately. Restart browser/computer!

Comment: You're right! It does work in Chrome if I go in the Incognito Mode which led me to believe it was something with the cookies. However I started Chrome (regularly) without any plugins and it worked, then took the plugins one by one and found the culprit: Measureit (https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/measureit/aonjhmdcgbgikgjapjckfkefpphjpgma). If this is loaded and enabled those tabs don't work, but if it's disabled they do. I've seen that in the console there is an error for the plugin, so if anyone experiences this problem this is the solution. Thank you for opening my eyes.

Comment: yes, as soon as I can vote up, right now it says I need 15 reputation.

Comment: @Claude There should be a green 'v'-mark under the number with arrows. That will mark the question as accepted